Next number in a sequence: 7, 15, 3, 11, 2, ...?
Find the next number, in the sequence:

7
15
3
11
2
10
6
14
8
...

Hint:

 This is a real sequence of numbers, generated by an old piece of electronic hardware (computer/microcontroller) I have lying around.

Additional Question (includes spoiler) - For those who have solved the initial question:

 Complete the entire sequence (16 numbers total).


That 8 at the end is surprising. I want to know what the thing uses this sequence for!

@codewarrior0 - Unit codes for home automation.

Well, now I can't figure out why it's sending the unit codes out of order.

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,$ be the given sequence.

 Then $a_{2n}=a_{2n-1}+8$ for each natural $n$.


 So the next member is $8+8=16$.


Zero would fit better.
